# Determine whether the following series converges or diverges ( root test or ratio test)

Tags: real-analysis

> Series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{(k!)^3}{(3k)!}\right]^k$

Attempted the root test but got a test that wasn't conclusive. Can you integrate two tests in one? Could I take the root test and then use the Ratio test?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the root test gives
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n!)^3}{(3n)!}=0\lt1$$
so the series converges.

Comment: How do we know that this is equal to 0?

Comment: @lj_growl $0\lt\frac{(n!)^3}{(3n)!}\lt \frac1n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. You should be able to prove this by induction.